Make BarChart responsive MUI-X and React
I'm trying to make this BarChart responsive, as of right now it has a fixed height (500x200px). The documentation is pretty vague and says to wrap the BarChart in a ResponsiveChartContainer, but I tried to do this every possible way and it either just made the whole Chart disappear or gave me errors. Anyone know how to do this properly?
import React from 'react';
import { BarChart } from '@mui/x-charts';

interface HighlightCounts {
    [key: string]: number;
}

interface MyBarChartComponentProps {
    counts: HighlightCounts;
}

class MyBarChartComponent extends React.Component<MyBarChartComponentProps> {
    render() {
        const { counts } = this.props;

        const xAxisConfig = {
            tickLabelInterval: (value: any, index: any) => Number.isInteger(value), // only full numbers bc these are counts
            valueFormatter: (value: any) => value.toFixed(0),
            label:'Votes'
        };

        // Transform the highlightCounts object into an array suitable for the BarChart
        const dataset = Object.entries(counts).map(([name, value]) => ({
            name,
            value
        }));

        return (
            <BarChart
                dataset={dataset}
                yAxis={[{ scaleType: 'band', dataKey: 'name' }]}
                xAxis={[xAxisConfig]}
                series={[
                    {
                        color:'#DBF881',
                        dataKey: 'value',
                        valueFormatter: (value) => `${value} votes`
                    }
                ]}
                width={500}
                height={200}
                layout="horizontal"
                borderRadius={5}
                margin={{ left: 75 }}
                sx={{
                    "& .MuiChartsAxis-left .MuiChartsAxis-tickLabel, & .MuiChartsAxis-bottom .MuiChartsAxis-tickLabel, &.MuiChartsAxis-tick, .MuiChartsAxis-label": {
                        strokeWidth: "0.4",
                        fill: "#fff"
                    },
                    "& .MuiChartsAxis-left .MuiChartsAxis-line, & .MuiChartsAxis-bottom .MuiChartsAxis-line, .MuiChartsAxis-tick": {
                        stroke: "#fff",
                        strokeWidth: 0.4,
                    }
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default MyBarChartComponent;

Sandbox: codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/barchart-h5w5tf
This is what it looks like rn:

What happens when you remove the width?
can you make a sandbox of your code

The chart just disappears (width & height seem to then be autmatically set to 0) ._.

wrap the bar in a <Box sx={{width: '100%'}}>?
If you make a sandbox i can take a look

The  doesnt work either bc still as soon as I remove the height/weight the chart disappears. Heresn a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/barchart-h5w5tf

Try using BarPlot inside ResponsiveChartContainer like
<ResponsiveChartContainer
  width={500}
  height={300}
  series={[{ data: uData, label: 'uv', type: 'bar' }]}
  xAxis={[{ scaleType: 'band', data: xLabels }]}
>
  <BarPlot />
</ResponsiveChartContainer>

Refer this.

@J_R at least one of the parents of the chart has to have a specific size for it to be responsive. Alternativelly, you can set only the "height" and the chart will be responsive with the given height.
On your example, you can replace you div with the code below and remove the height/width of your Chart component.
    <div style={{ height: "40vh" }}>
      <h2>Bar Chart with MUI and X-Charts</h2>
      <MyBarChartComponent counts={counts} />
    </div>

Another option would be to have only height set on the chart
    <BarChart
      dataset={dataset}
      yAxis={[{ scaleType: "band", dataKey: "name" }]}
      xAxis={[xAxisConfig]}
      series={[
        {
          color: "#DBF881",
          dataKey: "value",
          valueFormatter: (value) => `${value} votes`,
        },
      ]}
      layout="horizontal"
      height={200}
      borderRadius={5}
      margin={{ left: 75 }}
    />

